# AS3: limit objects to stage width?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I want to limit the creation of objects acording to the stage width.

My method is the following:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<7; i++){
```

If I put something like this, it won't work

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.width); i++){
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**Full code:**

```
    [SWF(width = 350, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
var sim:QuickBox2D = new QuickBox2D(this);  
sim.createStageWalls();  
// make a heavy circle  
sim.addCircle({x:3, y:3, radius:0.4, density:1});  
// create a few platforms  

// make 26 dominoes  
for (var i:int = 0; i<7; i++){  
//End
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:18, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:17, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:16, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:15, radius:0.1, density:0});

//Mid end

      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:14, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:13, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:12, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:11, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:10, radius:0.1, density:0});

}  
sim.start();  
sim.mouseDrag();
```

Comment: QuickBox doesn't like it.

I put : `for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth); i++){ `

Comment: And I get, this output error:

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Box2D.Collision::b2BroadPhase/CreateProxy()
 at Box2D.Collision.Shapes::b2Shape/CreateProxy()
 at Box2D.Dynamics::b2Body/CreateShape()
 `

Comment: Oh wait, is more than that, BOX2D works with meters, and stage works with pixels, I suppose I should find a way to say stageWith for BOX2D...

Comment: you can access the property stage.stageWidth only after the class has been ADDED_TO_STAGE. try to add an Event Listener for this event and put your for loop inside the callback function

Comment: ....reading your comments just now, I've never used BOX2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use stage.stageWidth

To explain it:

- stage.stageWidth is the width of the Flash Player
- stage.width is the width of content within the stage. So if you have nothing on the stage, stage.width would be 0.